# why i am getting that error ? fatal: Remote branch redux-basics not found in upstream origin

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-clone

I am using that command to clone a branch of a repository but I don't know why it throws that error

```
git clone -b redux-basics https://github.com/mschwarzmueller/reactjs-redux-basics.git
```

why that command returns me that

```
fatal: Remote branch redux-basics not found in upstream origin
```

please tell me what should I do next

Answer (score 2):

If you simply browse to [the URL you yourself supplied](https://github.com/mschwarzmueller/reactjs-redux-basics.git) and use GitHub's web interface to find the names of branches, you will see that this repository does not *have* a branch named `redux-basics`.

It *does* have a branch named `01-redux-basics` (listed in the "stale" section, last updated 5 years ago).

Answer (score 0):

You can find the list of available branches by using

```
git ls-remote --heads https://git.LINK_TO_REPO.git
```

which returns something like

```
46d0adaf08ef87d0aa840f9a4338d172bf931752    refs/heads/pilot/buildsplit
349502cbb72664c376b2392bdbe8179725a52012    refs/heads/testing/time
32670bd5f6014542d8f9f3854e5aebff5eb8dddf    refs/heads/testing/health
```

And if I want to clone e.g. the branch `time`, don't forget to **discard** the `refs/heads/` **part** and use

```
git clone --single-branch -b testing/time https://git.LINK_TO_REPO.git
```

Note that simply using commit hash instead of name doesn't work.